# Table-layout: fixed - IE8 delay render problem with dynamic content

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, rendering, tablelayout

I am using a table with style **table-layout:fixed** to solve wrap problems. The **table content is dynamic** produced with PHP. When the page is rendered, many cells content doens't appear!

The content appear if I pass the mouse up the cell. If I resize the window manually, all the cell content appear!

What I can do? I accept any solution! Can be javascript, CSS, PHP...

Thanks!

Simone

Comment: we would need an example table of data. make sure that you don't have any "empty" cells as IE tends to colapse those, have at least a &nbsp; (non-breaking space) in any otherwise empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to style the headers in the first row of the table in order to establish a width for each column.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:100px;">Header 1</th>
    <th style="width:100px;">Header 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```